# JavaScript Object - Different Type Depending on Context

Tags: javascript

I am going to start off by saying that I don't think this is possible, but hoping that someone knows some special way in JavaScript to do this. I have a JavaScript object defined as follows:

```
var t = {
  "fields": {
    "a": ["99", "98"]
  }
};
```

I am looking for a way so that I can define the same element of an array twice with different values that could be used in two different contexts - something like this:

```
var t = {
  "fields": {
    "a": ["99", "98"],
    "a": "99|98"
  }
};
```

If I was to query it using the syntax `t.fields["a"]` it would return "99|98" but if I was to query it using `t.fields["a"][0]` then it would return "99". I understand if I query an array without specifying an index then it returns "99,98" as a string - but I need it to return the entries delimited with a "|" instead of a ",".

Comment: I don't think you can, but it seems like an XY problem anyway... Why do you want to do this?

Comment: You could write a getter with a `type` parameter.

Comment: I am writing a tool which populates an array with data from a table - each row is filled into the array when it is processed (so "t" in my example is a row of data) - the actual element keys represent the header row. I am using this for templating / fancy mail merge. In some situations the values might be delimited by a "|" (or another character) and if so I want access to the original string value as well as split it out into an array. I could use a separate key (i.e. "a" for the original value and "aa" for the split values) but was looking to use the same key so it is simpler for the user.

Comment: I'd be more inclined to add a method to do it, perhaps something like `aConcat : function(c) { return this.a.join(c||"|"); }` and then call it as `t.fields.aConcat();` or `t.fields.aConcat(",")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve what you want you've got some options. Choose which option is the best for you depending on your coding style, environment, etc. Here you are.

### Option 1

You can easily replace the `.toString()` method of the `Array.prototype` to return values separated by a vertical line (`|`) instead of the usual comma. You can do it like this:

```
Array.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.join("|");
};
```

Now you can easily do what you want:

```
var t = {
    "fields": {
        "a": ["99", "98"]
    }
};

console.log("My array is: " + t.fields);
// My array is: 99|98

console.log("Its first element is: " + t.fields[0]); 
// Its first element is: 99
```

By the way, changing default objects' methods/properties is not always the best choice, because some libraries or native methods could use them and cause errors because they've been modified.

### Option 2

To achieve what you want, if you only have to do with a few arrays, you can modify their `prototype`s instead of the default `Array.prototype`, like this:

```
// Let's assume you have arrays a, b and c
var a = [1, 2],
    b = [3, 4],
    c = [5, 6];

a.toString =
b.toString =
c.toString = function() {
    return this.join("|");
};
```

This is a better way if you only work with few arrays, otherwise it would be heavy to change every prototype of every array you use, and would better do it with `Array.prototype` (like my first example).

### Option 3

Build your own function and use it. This is **recommended** because it doesn't change any existing `prototype` method, which could result in some errors depending on how you use your arrays.

```
// Create your own function
function myJoin(array) {
    return array.join("|");
}

var a = [1, 2, 3];
myJoin(a); // "1|2|3"

// Or add it to the prototype
Array.prototype.myJoin = function() {
    return this.join("|");
}

var b = [11, 22, 33];
b.myJoin(); // "11|22|33"
```

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for - I am going to give this a go. Although I probably only want to change it in the context of my object otherwise it would change the behaviour for other things. My tool provides users the ability to write their own JavaScript to extend it.

Comment: It does the job, however it's not really recommended to change common objects prototype: you must know that it will change the Array prototype not only in this specific case, but also for any other Array used, both in your code and in other JS code loaded in the page. Beware side effects!

Comment: @parchment just a longer way to do it

Comment: @Marco except it doesn't modify `Array.prototype`

Comment: Agree with parchment, this is much better

Comment: @parchment You are right, I added your solution to my answer, thanks a lot

Comment: a.prototype.toString = ... Will throw an exception. To override toString for only the instance you can do a.toString It's not a good idea to willy nilly change prototype of objects you don't own (Array.property):   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FInheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Bad_practice.3A_Extension_of_native_prototypes

Answer (score 3):

It's also possible to use a getter function, like this:

```
var t = {
    "fields": {
        "_a": ["99", "98"],
        "a": function (index) {
            if (typeof index != 'undefined')
                return this._a[index];
            else
                return this._a.join('|');
        }
    }
};

console.log(t.fields['a']()); // 99|98
console.log(t.fields['a'](1));// 98
```

You can also have a global get function for all the fields:

```
var t = {
    "fields": {
        "_a": ["99", "98"],
        get: function (field, index) {
            if (typeof index != 'undefined')
                return this['_' + field][index];
            else
                return this['_' + field].join('|');
        }
    }
};

console.log(t.fields.get('a')); // 99|98
console.log(t.fields.get('a', 1)); // 98
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to close this off, thanks to @marco-bonelli and everyone else I have settled with the following:

```
var t = {
  "fields": {
    "a": ["99", "98"],
    "b": ["77", "76"]
  },
  "token": "|"
};

Object.keys(t).forEach(function(key) {
  t.fields[key].toString = function() {
    return this.join(t.token);
  };
});
```

The "t" object is dynamically generated from user data (with careful escaping) so there could be multiple elements within the "fields" object.